# Python Error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file? Code below

Tags: python

```
log = open("exeoutput.txt", "w")
sys.stdout = log 
cmd="cksum `ls -lrt | grep -v ^d | awk '{print $9}'`"
ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = ps.communicate()[0]
print(output)
log.close()

print "File has been executed successfully.\n"
```

Result: Output file got created successfully, but it raised an error for print statement.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 19, in <module>
    print "File has been executed successfully.\n"
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: This looks like a clear and reproducible example. Could you state your question a bit more explicitly? Also, some information about your OS and configuration may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replaced `sys.stdout` with a file handle then closed it. Unless you put the original file object back, future prints will fail. You could save the original stdout and replace it when done.

```
log = open("exeoutput.txt", "w")
stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = log 
cmd="cksum `ls -lrt | grep -v ^d | awk '{print $9}'`"
ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = ps.communicate()[0]
print(output)
log.close()
sys.stdout = stdout

print "File has been executed successfully.\n"
```

Comment: @KUNALTHAKUR - Since it works, accept this answer (the checkmark) so that others don't think you still need a solution.